# Grepping exact difference

Tags: awk, grep

I have two text files like

a

```
1111|100|11/11/1111|a
2222|200|11/11/1111|a
3333|300|11/11/1111|a
4444|400|11/11/1111|a
```

b

```
1111|100|11/11/1111|a
1111|100|11/11/1111|a
2222|200|11/11/1111|a
3333|300|11/11/1111|a
5555|500|11/11/1111|a
```

I have used below command

```
awk -F"|" '{ printf "%4s|%3s|\n",$1,$2 }' a | grep -v -f /dev/stdin b
```

which outputs....

```
5555|500|11/11/1111|a
```

expected output was

```
1111|100|11/11/1111|a
5555|500|11/11/1111|a
```

How can i do this with `grep` or `awk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more general approach to comparing any number of unsorted files using GNU awk for arrays of arrays and ARGIND:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
{ cnt[$0][ARGIND]++ }
END {
    for (str in cnt) {
        for (fileNr=1; fileNr<=ARGIND; fileNr++) {
            printf "%d%s", cnt[str][fileNr], OFS
        }
        print str
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk a b
1       2       1111|100|11/11/1111|a
1       1       2222|200|11/11/1111|a
1       1       3333|300|11/11/1111|a
1       0       4444|400|11/11/1111|a
0       1       5555|500|11/11/1111|a
```

The above shows each unique string across all the files along with how many times the given string appears in the first file, how many in the second, etc.

To get the output you wanted then can simply be:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk a b | awk '$2>$1' | cut -f3-
1111|100|11/11/1111|a
5555|500|11/11/1111|a
```

Answer (score 2):

`grep` would not be suitable here as it's used to extract individual lines that matches some form of regular expression (not for comparing files really). It would not be able to return one match and discard another (the first two lines of your file `b`).

You could use `comm`:

```
$ comm -13 a b
1111|100|11/11/1111|a
5555|500|11/11/1111|a
```

Note that `comm` relies on sorted input data.

The `comm` command above uses `-13` to discard the first and third columns in its default output.  By default, it would output the lines only found in the first file in column 1, lines only found in the second file in column 2 and common line in the last column (see the manual for `comm` on your system, it's [a standard utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/comm.html)):

```
$ comm a b
                1111|100|11/11/1111|a
        1111|100|11/11/1111|a
                2222|200|11/11/1111|a
                3333|300|11/11/1111|a
4444|400|11/11/1111|a
        5555|500|11/11/1111|a
```